# Required ecommerce multivendor application using react and node source code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, e-commerce

I want a free open sourcecode for ecommerce application with react and nodejs. It should have customer,vendor,admin modules seperately.Do anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can have a look to [medusajs](https://www.medusajs.com/) but unfortunately there is no feature for multi vendor management.

However, this feature is plan and should start next year if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out https://github.com/medusajs/medusa

And yes, you can use react with it.

Visit https://www.medusajs.com/ for more info

Answer (score -1):

Spurtcommerce Open source Multi-Vendor eCommerce solution is on the latest tech stack of NodeJS , Typescript With Angular and React and has been built on the trending concept of B2B , B2C commerce. Now, in the upcoming version 4.8, Spurtcommerce is coming up with its whole new transformation - Addon support features .

For more details Download Source code , visit
https://www.spurtcommerce.com